# Java/My Batis not returning boolean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mapping, mybatis

I have this chunk in the controller:

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
public boolean isWorkflowCoordinatorExistingForStep(final long workflowStepId) {
    Validate.notNull(workflowStepId, "workflow step id cannot be null");
    return (boolean) this.auditingSqlSession.selectOne("isWorkflowCoordinatorExistingForStep", workflowStepId);
}
```

That maps with this:

```
<select id="isWorkflowCoordinatorExistingForStep" resultType="java.lang.Boolean">
        SELECT is_coordinator
        FROM mo_subject_privileges
        WHERE workflow_step_id = #{workflowStepId}


</select>
```

It seems fine to me, but it is not: I am getting a "`Inconvertible types. Cannot cast java.lang.Object to boolean`"

Any hint?

Comment: try changing `boolean` to `Boolean` simple types might be confusing it.

Answer (score 2):

Its possible that the data is stored in your Database as a string rather than a boolean, as is often the case. Maybe add a println(selectone.tostring()) to make sure that the output is 'TRUE' and not 'T' for example.

Answer (score 1):

Does your Database support Booleans?

For instance Oracle has no native Boolean, so it might be possible, that mybatis does not support Booleans.

Try something else: Select the row and then check in your DAO-Method if the special field is a boolean.

**DAO:**

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
public boolean isWorkflowCoordinatorExistingForStep(final long workflowStepId) {
    Validate.notNull(workflowStepId, "workflow step id cannot be null");
    SomeObject so = (SomeObject) this.auditingSqlSession.selectOne("isWorkflowCoordinatorExistingForStep", workflowStepId);
    return so.isCoordinator(); // if neccassary, check for null
}
```

**XML-Map:**

```
<select id="isWorkflowCoordinatorExistingForStep" resultType="path.to.SomeObject">
        SELECT *
        FROM mo_subject_privileges
        WHERE workflow_step_id = #{workflowStepId}   
</select>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help, but I am looking forward to retrieve a boolean an not an object. Do you think it will be compatible if I retrieve a String?

Comment: which values returns your select?

Answer (score 0):

You check whether the field is String in DB. 
You can decode the value

```
DECODE(is_coordinator,'t', true, 'f', false)
```